# Set a custom style to tags recognized by Html.fromHtml()

Tags: android, html, textview, format, styles

In Android, when setting html formatted text in a `TextView` using `Html.fromHtml()`, text styling is applied to e.g. the `h1` heading tag. The style Android uses does not fit with the style of my app.

Is it possible to apply custom text styles / formatting to the recognized html tags?

So that e.g. all `h1` tags are styled in the same custom way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom style attributes to your texviews but you cannot override the HTML tags, those tags are predefined standards and cannot be changed.

Comment: Any idea how to style a html string using the standard material design styles of the support library?
Splitting the html string in tags and adding these as separate TextViews is one idea.

Comment: Sorry I am not getting what you are saying.Can you just show me some sample images or something to elaborate the actual requirement? So I can understand.